# Cannot mark for Add files in perforce

Tags: perforce

I wrote 2 python scripts which I want to add to changelist in perforce. So in my workspace (in perforce gui) I created a folder /pythonP and using my unix file manager I copied paste my 2 python scripts in /pythonP, which is in my workspace (not in depot because I just created and didn't submit anything) So in perforce I can see in my workspace my 2 python scripts, but when I try to put them in a changelist (drag and drop or right-click:add to mark) I get no error messages but the files just don't appear in the changelist. I right-clicked on the changelist and the 'Files' section is empty. Any suggestions?!

Comment: Try doing it from the commandline (with `p4 add`) and you should get a more helpful diagnostic.

Comment: I get the following warning:no files opened, file(s) not in client view. That's probably because I copied the file from my local disk and not from the depot right? Do you know the solution to that?

Comment: Have you selected the correct workspace in the Perforce GUI? Is `/pythonP` a subfolder of where the workspace is kept on your local disk?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "File(s) not in client view" error indicates that the folder the files you're trying to add are in, is not part of your mapped workspace. Either you don't have anything mapped in your workspace view, or the place your files are, is not the place Perforce is controlling.

One thing you can do is to right-click on the depot directory in the depot view, and select "show in explorer". The folder that opens is where Perforce expects your files to be.

I should explain: A Perforce repository is not like an FTP site, where you copy files from the local place to the remote place. To add a file to Perforce, you put it where you want it to be in your local copy of the depot, and then tell Perforce to start tracking it (with `p4 add`). The addition does not move or copy the file. (Of course, the file content does get copied to the Perforce server... but logically, *you're* putting the file in your workspace, not having Perforce do that for you.)

Comment: Thanks, I mapped /pythonP to the depot and it worked :)

Answer (score 4):

Try updating your workspace. I had this problem when someone else had added a file, my workspace was out of date, and I was trying to add a file with the same name in the same location.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem right now and I not found solution. It was depot folder where project files shold be. After added to workspace 'depot' folder and move project files inside, add and submiting works.